# Could a Google account be lost without the user deleting it?

Tags: google-account

I am the admin of several Google accounts through GSuite that uses a custom domain. I have disabled the account deletion feature for the Google accounts I manage. However, I am wondering if the accounts are simply unable to be deleted at all, or if they are just unable to be deleted by the user. I am aware that I can delete the Google accounts if necessary. However, is there a way that the Google accounts could be lost (meaning destroyed, deleted, erased, completely inaccessable, hopelessly corrupted, hacked and piloted for illegal purposes leading to a useless account, etc.) Without me or Google or the student deleting it through a soft delete?

I am specifically worried that a student could lose their academic progress if something happened to the account (if that is even possible).

Comment: @BlindSpots sorry, I had a school meeting to go to. I edited the question.

Comment: Question still unclear. What's meant by ***have disabled the account deletion feature*** E.g. to **delete** Workspace User, one should have ``Admin role > User Management Admin > Privileges > Users > Delete``  Edit question to change **Gsuite** to **Google Workspace** If relevant, specify tier (starter, standard, plus, enterprise). State your Admin role (e.g. Super, Groups, User Mgt, etc.).  Questions that encourage opinions are discouraged. See [How do I ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)